# How can i use promises to populate object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small issue..  Im depending on 2 services, where I loop all organizations, and for each organization, i loop the systems connected to the organization, pushing each system to an object. That works great, and no problem here... the problem comes when I create my map, because at this point, the this.systemList object is empty... So I only want my createMap() function to be called when im done adding all items to the array (this.systemList)

So somehow i want to check for if all organizations, and all systems has done looping, and all systems has been added to the: `this.systemList` array, and first here call the `this.createMap()`

### Hope it makes sense?

Check out the code here:

```
methods: {
    getSystemsForOrganization(orgId) {
        SystemService.getSystemsForOrganization(orgId).then((response) => {
            let systems = response.data.systems;
            let systemPromises = [];
            if(systems) {
                systems.forEach((system, index, array) => {
                    let systemHasAlarms = !!system.pending_events;

                    let systemObject = {
                        id: system.id,
                        name: system.name,
                        latitude: system.latitude,
                        longitude: system.longitude,
                        latlng: [system.latitude, system.longitude],
                        has_alarms: systemHasAlarms
                    };
                    this.systemList.push(systemObject);
                });
            }
        });
    },
    getCurrentOrganizations() {
        OrganizationService.getOrganizationData().then((response) => {
            let organizations = response.data.organizations;

            let organizationsIds = organizations.map((org) => {
                return org.id;
            });

            organizationsIds.forEach((id, index, array) => {
                this.getSystemsForOrganization(id);
            });
        });

    },
},
mounted() {
    this.getCurrentOrganizations();
    this.createMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the code should be self explanatory

Your main issue is not returning promises to wait for

```
methods: {
    getSystemsForOrganization(orgId) {
        // added "return" to return the promise so you can wait on it
        return SystemService.getSystemsForOrganization(orgId).then((response) => {
            let systems = response.data.systems;
            let systemPromises = [];
            if(systems) {
                systems.forEach((system, index, array) => {
                    let systemHasAlarms = !!system.pending_events;

                    let systemObject = {
                        id: system.id,
                        name: system.name,
                        latitude: system.latitude,
                        longitude: system.longitude,
                        latlng: [system.latitude, system.longitude],
                        has_alarms: systemHasAlarms
                    };
                    this.systemList.push(systemObject);
                });
            }
        });
    },
    getCurrentOrganizations() {
        // return the promise
        return OrganizationService.getOrganizationData().then((response) => {
            let organizations = response.data.organizations;

            let organizationsIds = organizations.map((org) => {
                return org.id;
            });
            // instead of organizationsIds.forEach, use organizationsIds.map, so we
            // have an array of promises for Promise.all to wait on
            let promises = organizationsIds.map(id => {
                return this.getSystemsForOrganization(id);
            });
            // returns a Promise that "waits" for all promises to resolve
            return Promise.all(promises);
        });

    },
},
mounted() {
    this.getCurrentOrganizations().then(() => {
        this.createMap();
    });
}
```

the code can also be "simplified" to

```
methods: {
    getSystemsForOrganization(orgId) {
        // added "return" to return the promise so you can wait on it
        return SystemService.getSystemsForOrganization(orgId).then(({data}) => 
            this.systemList.push(
                ...(data.systems||[])
                .map(({id, name, latitude, longitude, pending_events})=> ({
                    id,
                    name,
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    latlng: [latitude, longitude],
                    has_alarms: !!pending_events
                }))
            )
        );
    },
    getCurrentOrganizations() {
        return OrganizationService.getOrganizationData()
        .then(response => 
            Promise.all(response.data.organizations
                .map(({id}) => this.getSystemsForOrganization(id))
            )
        );
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.getCurrentOrganizations().then(this.createMap);
}
```